# How can I optimize the searching of two tables?

Tags: mysql, search, optimization

I have two tables:

1st:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `i` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `k` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`i`),
  KEY `k` (`k`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1505426 ;
```

and 2nd:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `w` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `k1` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `k2` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `k3` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `k4` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `k5` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `k6` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `k7` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `k8` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `w` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `h` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `s` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `r` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `v` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `c` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `c1` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `c3` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `c4` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `c5` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `c6` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `m` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `t` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `i` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `o` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `f` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `keywords` (`k1`,`k2`,`k3`,`k4`,`k5`,`k6`,`k7`,`k8`),
  KEY `category` (`c`),
  KEY `color1` (`c1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

I'm trying to search 2 words ($search1 + $search2) from table 'tags' and find id's at 'w' table.
 query:

```
SELECT w.id,w.title,w.k1,w.k2,w.k3,w.k4,w.k5,w.k6,w.k7,w.w,w.h,w.s,w.c1,w.c2,w.c3,w.c4,w.c5,w.c6,w.m,w.f
FROM tags,tags as tags2,w
WHERE tags.k ='$search1' AND tags2.k = '$search2'
and tags.id = tags2.id and tags2.id = w.id
ORDER BY `w`.`id`desc limit 24
```

The problem is that EXPLAIN function shows "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
Also I believe that there is another way to optimize this my type search system.
Actually all data is in 'w' table, I just have no idea how exactly to search it properly.
I would be grateful for any help.

**Edit**:a bit more information about this

table 'tags' 1505425 records InnoDB = 65,9 MiB

table 'w' 398900 rercords, InnoDB = 140,3 MiB

after this (**updated**) query:

```
select `w`.`id` AS `id`,`w`.`title` AS `title`,`w`.`k1` AS `k1`,`w`.`k2` AS `k2`,`w`.`k3` AS `k3`,`w`.`k4` AS `k4`,`w`.`k5` AS `k5`,`w`.`k6` AS `k6`,`w`.`k7` AS `k7`,`w`.`k8` AS `k8`,`w`.`w` AS `w`,`w`.`h` AS `h`,`w`.`s` AS `s`,`w`.`c1` AS `c1`,`w`.`c2` AS `c2`,`w`.`c3` AS `c3`,`w`.`c4` AS `c4`,`w`.`c5` AS `c5`,`w`.`c6` AS `c6`,`w`.`m` AS `m`,`w`.`f` AS `f` from `tags` join `tags` `tags2` join `w` where ((`tags`.`k` = '$search1') and (`tags2`.`id` = `tags`.`id`) and (`w`.`id` = `tags`.`id`) and (`tags2`.`k` = '$search2')) order by `tags`.`i` desc limit 0,24;
```

mysql still shows:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags       | ref    | k,id          | k       | 98      | const       |  902 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags2      | ref    | k,id          | id      | 4       | db.tags.id  |    4 |   100.00 | Using where                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | w          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | db.tags2.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

One warning, also still everything remains the same, is there any solution for better performance? At the moment it works fine, but later everything will goes slower and slower I think.

Comment: Those are some very descriptive column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing storage engines; mySQL has a hard time joining tables across storage engines.

Before:

```
mysql> explain SELECT w.id,w.title,w.k1,w.k2,w.k3,w.k4,w.k5,w.k6,w.k7,w.w,w.h,w.s,w.c1,w.c2,w.c3,w.c4,w.c5,w.c6,w.m,w.f FROM tags,tags as tags2,w WHERE tags.k ='$search1' AND tags2.k = 'search2' and tags.id = tags2.id and tags2.id = w.id ORDER BY `w`.`id`desc limit 24;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags  | ref    | k             | k       | 98      | const       |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags2 | ref    | k             | k       | 98      | const       |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | w     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | tmp.tags.id |    1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Change w to MyISAM:

```
mysql> alter table w engine MyISAM;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

After:

```
mysql> explain SELECT w.id,w.title,w.k1,w.k2,w.k3,w.k4,w.k5,w.k6,w.k7,w.w,w.h,w.s,w.c1,w.c2,w.c3,w.c4,w.c5,w.c6,w.m,w.f FROM tags,tags as tags2,w WHERE tags.k ='$search1' AND tags2.k = 'search2' and tags.id = tags2.id and tags2.id = w.id ORDER BY `w`.`id`desc limit 24;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | w     | system | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL  |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags  | ref    | k             | k    | 98      | const |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags2 | ref    | k             | k    | 98      | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've tried, but nothing happend. I've forgot to say that 'w' table have huge update rate in a second, so if i'm not wrong it would be better to keep as innodb?, also whole table records up to ~400k and size ~100MB

Comment: Yes, it would be best to keep it in InnoDB if it has a lot of updates. I was wrong in saying the problem was with the mixed engines: the "using filesort" reappears when both tables use InnoDB.

Comment: The real cause for the "using filesort" is the "order by w.id" -- do you really need that ordering? If you just need a replicable order so you can page, ordering by tags.i got me rid of the "using filesort".

Comment: i prefer to select latest records and to keep them on top, so it should be last record from 'w' table,  the problem is only when i'm searching 2 words, id with word1 must be the same id and with word2.maybe is there any other solution to do like this?

Answer (score 0):

Vagiz, your updated query seems OK:

```
select `w`.`id` AS `id`,`w`.`title` AS `title`,`w`.`k1` AS `k1`,`w`.`k2` AS `k2`,
`w`.`k3` AS `k3`,`w`.`k4` AS `k4`,`w`.`k5` AS `k5`,`w`.`k6` AS `k6`,`w`.
`k7` AS `k7`,`w`.`k8` AS `k8`,`w`.`w` AS `w`,`w`.`h` AS `h`,`w`.`s` AS `s`,
`w`.`c1` AS `c1`,`w`.`c2` AS `c2`,`w`.`c3` AS `c3`,`w`.`c4` AS `c4`,
`w`.`c5` AS `c5`,`w`.`c6` AS `c6`,`w`.`m` AS `m`,`w`.`f` AS `f`
from `tags` join `tags` `tags2` join `w` where ((`tags`.`k` = '$search1') 
and (`tags2`.`id` = `tags`.`id`) and (`w`.`id` = `tags`.`id`) 
and (`tags2`.`k` = '$search2')) order by `tags`.`i` desc limit 0,24;
```

If it's producing following explain result:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags       | ref    | k,id          | k       | 98      | const       |  902 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags2      | ref    | k,id          | id      | 4       | db.tags.id  |    4 |   100.00 | Using where                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | w          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | db.tags2.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Don't worry about filesort and performance. From the [Mysql Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/):

> The truth is, filesort is badly named. Anytime a sort can’t be
>   performed from an index, it’s a filesort. It has nothing to do with
>   files. Filesort should be called “sort.” It is quicksort at heart.

Comment: but still i care about that "3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)" warning, i'm wondering what's wrong with that query

Comment: Ok, what's the output of SHOW WARNINGS after explain extended? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-warnings.html

Comment: "| Note  | 1003 | " i cant add it as comment, due comment characters limit